# Multiple divs with the same name withs forms

Tags: jquery, html

I have a multiples divs, and I want How I can detect the div I clicked and get the values inputs from the Div I clicked

```
<div class="Offers">
    <div class="txt">
    </div>
    <div class="map">
    <form id="vmap" method="post">
        <input type=hidden id=idship value=64>
        <input type=hidden id=iddate value=1254>
        <button>View Map</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Offers">
    <div class="txt">
    </div>
    <div class="map">
        <form id="vmap" method="post">
            <input type=hidden id=idship value=65>
            <input type=hidden id=iddate value=1255>
            <button>View Map</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Offers">
    <div class="txt">
    </div>
    <div class="map">
        <form id="vmap" method="post">
            <input type=hidden id=idship value=66>
            <input type=hidden id=iddate value=1256>
            <button>View Map</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How I can detect the div I clicked and get the correct values from the inputs?

Comment: where is your script ?

Comment: duplicate id's ... invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Offers">
    <div class="txt">
    </div>
    <div class="map">
    <form id="vmap" method="post">
        <input type=hidden id=idship value=64>
        <input type=hidden id=iddate value=1254>
        <button>View Map</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Offers">
    <div class="txt">
    </div>
    <div class="map">
        <form id="vmap" method="post">
            <input type=hidden id=idship value=65>
            <input type=hidden id=iddate value=1255>
            <button>View Map</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Offers">
    <div class="txt">
    </div>
    <div class="map">
        <form id="vmap" method="post">
            <input type=hidden id=idship value=66>
            <input type=hidden id=iddate value=1256>
            <button>View Map</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"  type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script>
$(function () {

$(".Offers .map button").on('click', function() {
    var form=$(this).parent("form");
    var idship =form.find('#idship').val();
    var iddate =form.find('#iddate').val();
    alert(idship +"---------"+iddate);
  });


});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Th html5 spec says

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.

If you make each id unique, it is easy to select exactly what you want in jquery with

`$("#ID-here").val()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```js
  
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.map').click(function(){
 var input1 = $(this).find('input#idship').val();
 var input2 = $(this).find('input#iddate').val();
 alert("input1 - "+input1+" input2 - "+input2);
});  
});
```

```html
<div class="Offers">
    <div class="txt">
    </div>
    <div class="map">
    <form id="vmap" method="post">
        <input type='hidden' id='idship' value='64'>
        <input type='hidden' id='iddate' value='1254'>
        <button>View Map</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Offers">
    <div class="txt">
    </div>
    <div class="map">
        <form id="vmap" method="post">
            <input type='hidden' id='idship' value='65'>
            <input type='hidden' id='iddate' value='1255'>
            <button>View Map</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Offers">
    <div class="txt">
    </div>
    <div class="map">
        <form id="vmap" method="post">
            <input type='hidden' id='idship' value='66'>
            <input type='hidden' id='iddate' value='1256'>
            <button>View Map</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```